# Flickr API random div background

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I want to get a random photo with the flickr api with a tag of "landscape". The random photo link seems to be added programaticly in the html on inspect element in ChromeDevTools. But there is no photo. What am I doing wrong?

```
    $(document).ready(function() {


      $.getJSON("https://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?jsoncallback=?",
               {
                  tags: "landscape",
                  format: "json"
                },

                //The callback function
                function(data) {

                  //Get random photo from the api's items array
                    var randomPhoto = data.items[Math.floor(Math.random() * data.items.length)];  


                    $(".portret").css({


                      position: "relative",
                      height: "100vh",
                    //Use the randomPhoto's link
                      backgroundImage: "url("+randomPhoto.link+")",
                      backgroundPosition: "center",
                      backgroundRepeat: "no-repeat",
                      backgroundSize: "cover"
                    });
                }

               );




    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `media` object to  set the backgroung image.

The ´link´ attribute you are using is not correct, this is the link of a Flickr photo detail. You only need the url of the image.

Try it:

```
            $.getJSON("https://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?jsoncallback=?",
               {
                  tags: "landscape",
                  format: "json"
                },

                //The callback function
                function(data) {

                  //Get random photo from the api's items array
                    var randomPhoto = data.items[Math.floor(Math.random() * data.items.length)];  


                    $(".portret").css({


                      position: "relative",
                      height: "100vh",
                    //Use the randomPhoto's link
                      backgroundImage: "url("+randomPhoto.media.m+")",
                      backgroundPosition: "center",
                      backgroundRepeat: "no-repeat",
                      backgroundSize: "cover"
                    });
                 }
             );
```